# How could I use pytest-html in Pycharm?

Tags: pytest, pytest-html

I have installed pytest-html and want to use it generate html report after run pytest in pycharm.

like this:
[image: configure]

but it pops error:

```
ERROR: file not found: html=report\result.html
```

after run. So how to modify the arguments?

Answer (score 6):

use

```
--html=Reports/Report.html  --self-contained-html
```

in additional argument section of pycharm

Answer (score 0):

If your using terminal to run the test try this instead this will work .

```
py.test --html=demoreport.html
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run via pycharm, just by Right click on the project, follow below steps:

1. Add new configuration in Pycharm: At Configuration popup: Click '+', Python tests->pytest, provide "working directory" and "target" values with the path of the project.
2. Then after, Create a new file pytest.ini in the root folder of the project and provide the below values:

   ```
    [pytest]
    addopts = --html=reports/Report.html
    python_files = tests/*.py
   ```

where, tests/*.py is a folder which contains all tests.

Now, just right click on your project and select Run 'pytest in ProjectFolderName' and you will find that report is created inside reports folder with name Report.html